# Android JNI makefiles: where to set CFLAGS?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, cortex-a8

I'm stuck figuring out how exactly to tell Android to use VFP on Cortex-A8 for floating-point operations in my native C code. I know the compiler flags I need to set. The question is where do I do it? Can someone guide me through the process?

I'm using Eclipse. I use Cygwin to run ndk-build. My program works, so I've definitely got the procedure figured out. The question is *where* (in which file) do I tell Android to use VFP? The command is something like `CFLAGS += -mfpu=vfp`. When I insert this code into Android.mk, nothing happens.

Comment: The VFP tag that you attached stands for Visual FoxPro. I don't think it's relevant to your question.

Comment: No, it stands for vectorized floating point on ARM CPU architecture.

Comment: But here on StackOverflow, the VFP tag has been assigned to relate to Visual FoxPro. You can see that by hovering your mouse over the tag and waiting for the description to come up. Thus, your message is showing up as if it has something to do with Visual FoxPro.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't realize what you were talking about. I'll remove the tag. I think I misread your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line you need in Android.mk is LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mfpu=vfp